# Download full size image link in drupal 7 gallery

Tags: drupal-7, gallery, drupal-views

I've created a little gallery in drupal 7 using views module and colorbox formatter for image field. The thing is, I'd like to provide url for full size image download. Mind You - "full size image" is not the same image that appears in colorbox overlay. In fact I don't have full size image at all, since I've limited max image dimension on upload (1000 x 1000px). And I'm not sure how to overcome this restriction.

So, user should be able to click on a thumbnail (100 x 100px) and view 1000px wide version of an image in colorbox overlay. And apart from that there should be download link to full size photo (4000px wide, for example) - preferably in an overlay, but may be on the gallery page as well.

I could just skip size limits on upload and pull the link from image src, but I wanted to save bandwith and speed up display. Well, creating a gallery full of 16 Mpx photos isn't the way to go, anyway.

Is there any clever way to achieve what I want, or do I just need to hack file upload module a bit?

Comment: Well if you're limiting the size of uploads but want people to be able to download it, it's never going to work obviously. And if you wish to save bandwith, allowing people to download quite big pictures won't help neither.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. First of all, there should be (I guess) a way to upload 3 versions of an image. But it seems that I need to change upload module or write a module of my own. As to the bandwidth - it's a sports event gallery, so people will be downloading full versions of photos only if they are actually on the photo, and will browse through the rest. Or so I hope :-)

Comment: when dealing with multiple image size, I think the best is to let people upload their image, then create the smaller versions (1000px and thumbnails in your case) to use in your code. But anyway, if bandwith and/or disk space is a real concern, you may need to use a CDN to host your images. You can't rely on an expected behavior of users. Note also that even flickr stores full resolution images but only let Paying users download it back... maybe you should keep the limit down to 1000px ?

Comment: Bandwidth/space is not technical concern, at least not on my side. But it can be limiting factor on users side - even with image preloading 16 Mpx may take a while to display. As to the upload - I agree, but how exactly to upload image first and resize later, using standard or multi upload image field in drupal? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found an answer. And it's pretty simple, now that I think of it.

Since image derivatives are created on the fly, I just needed to create another image style in admin/config/media/image-styles, 1000px wide and high, and remove upload limit in image field.

"Full size download link" may be then created by a regex in JS, just replace one path to image with another.